# How to Reduce Values in a List in R

Tags: r, list

New R learner here. I have a list of odd numbers that I produced in R. I have 1. . .23 odd. "Three" is supposed to be spelled out. I only need the rows with the values of 1-11 odd not 13-23 odd. I am unable to reduce the list to be 1-11. How can I get rid of the values that are not needed?

```
for (i in 0:11)
{  
  i<-(i*2+1)
  {
    if (i <= 11)
    { 
      if (i == 3) ("three")
    } 
  } 
  print(i)
}

[1] 1
[1] 3
[1] 5
[1] 7
[1] 9
[1] 11
[1] 13
[1] 15
[1] 17
[1] 19
[1] 21
[1] 23
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-arranging and tweaking your code

```r
for (i in 0:11){
  i <- (i*2+1)
  if(i==3){
    print("Three")
    next
  }
  if(i<=11){
    print(i)
  }

}
#Output
# [1] 1
# [1] "Three"
# [1] 5
# [1] 7
# [1] 9
# [1] 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R one liner:

```
ifelse(c(1:11)[1:11 %% 2  > 0] == 3, "three", c(1:11)[1:11 %% 2  > 0])
```

Maintaining flow control in loop (as requested):

```
x <- vector("character", sum(0:11 %% 2 >0))
seq_vals <- 1:11
odd_vals <- seq_vals[1:11 %% 2  > 0] 
for(i in odd_vals){

  if(i != 3){

    x <- c(x, as.character(i))

  }else{

      x <- c(x, "three")

  }

}

x[x != ""]
```

Comment: Hoping to maintain the structure of the nested if statement within the for loop.

Comment: @Brandon Please see the edited code above. Also please accept this answer and upvote it if it has solved your problem.